# tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed) AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'app'

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am trying to follow the Tensor flow for poets guide for ML image classification. As of now I can't retrain my data set as I am presented with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
   "__main__", mod_spec)
 File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
   exec(code, run_globals)
 File "C:\Users\I352778\tensorflow-for-poets-2\tensorflow-for-poets-2\scripts\retrain.py", line 1326, in <module>
   tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'app'
```

Now I understand this is an issue due to running v1 feature and i am using Tensorflow v2 but still unsure hwo I can get around this. The training code i used is the following:

```
C:\Users\I352778\tensorflow-for-poets-2\tensorflow-for-poets-2>python -m scripts.retrain ^
More?   --bottleneck_dir=tf_files/bottlenecks ^
More?   --model_dir=tf_files/models/%ARCHITECTURE% ^
More?   --summaries_dir=tf_files/training_summaries/%ARCHITECTURE% ^
More?   --output_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb ^
More?   --output_labels=tf_files/retrained_labels.txt ^
More?   --architecture=%ARCHITECTURE% ^
More?   --image_dir=tf_files/C:\Users\I352778\Pictures\dataset-resized
```

How or what code should I be inputting to overcome the fact im trying to implement a v1 feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recording to the documentation of TensorFlow 2.0 the "**app**" attribuite has been removed: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/effective_tf2

"Many APIs are either gone or moved in TF 2.0. Some of the major changes include removing tf.app, tf.flags, and tf.logging...".
To resolve this, either uninstall tensorflow 2 and then install 1, or change your piece of code, I am not sure that going around this will help you alot, because Tensorflow is a very sensitive environment when you use it with Python, especially for the versions thing. so I think changing a little bit in the code would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this import `import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf`

Comment: Can you try running with this command. `tf.compat.v1.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change "import tensorflow as tf" with "import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf"

Comment: This is not an answer.